# What is the preferred way to structure type declaration files with Vite in React TypeScript app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, type-declaration

I am migrating my app from Webpack to Vite. What is the preferred way to add this:

`/// <reference types="vite/client" />`

I have already a file `types/global.d.ts`. Also I created a file `env.d.ts` and added:

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

interface ImportMetaEnv {
  readonly VITE_MY_ENDPOINT: string;
  // more env variables...
}

interface ImportMeta {
  readonly env: ImportMetaEnv;
}
```

But then I have 2 times the reference `/// <reference types="vite/client" />`.

What is the best way to structure this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called "vite-env.d.ts":

Contents of the file should be:

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

For me I saved this file in my /src folder.

Adding this file means you only need add this in a single time.